# Do I need to display copyright information of third-party libraries?

Tags: licensing, copyright, linked-libraries

My software project is using several third party libraries which have different licenses (LGPL, MIT, BSD). I distribute the dlls of those libraries, and I understand that I need to give license information and if the license demands it (like LGPL) acknowledge the use.

I sometimes see, that some programs have separate copyright sections, where they list the copyright holders of the third party licenses? Is this necessary?

Comment: Is your software a library or an application? The licenses of your dependencies only matter when you give someone a copy of these dependencies, and that's usually only an issue if you provide an installer or pre-built application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to do this.  Most of the licences you list don't demand a general-purpose acknowledgement, they specifically require that the copyright notice be preserved; this is often seen as sufficient acknowledgment, also.

BSD 3-clause says:

> Redistributions in binary form must reproduce **the above copyright
>       notice**, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
>       the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
>       distribution.

MIT X11 says:

> The **above copyright notice** and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

and LGPLv3 says:

> For a Combined Work that displays copyright notices during execution, **include the copyright notice** for the Library among these notices, as well as a reference directing the user to the copies of the GNU GPL and this license document.

LGPLv3 does have a more general "prominent notice" requirement, but the requirement to preserve copyright notices is sufficiently widespread that preservation of them all is a good idea, as well as courteous to those authors - as if your work is a derivative of theirs, then they actually do have a copyright interest in it.

Comment: The GPL (and LGPL, by extension) also has a requirement about preserving "Appropriate Legal Notices". If applicable these could also apply to some functionality of the program like a command line option or menu command which display copyright information. However many programs (e.g. non-GNU programs) do not have any such notices built-in, so the requirement is not relevant.  The "Promiment Notice" language requirement only applies to source code.

Comment: @Brandin LGPLv2 has no such requirement that I can immediately find; GPLv3's (which I acknowledge LGPLv3 doesn't waive) only requires them in interactive mode, and then only if that facility was already present.  The point I was trying to get across was that although *GPL's requirements are a bit more complex than those of the non-copyleft licences, the latter definitely require preservation of copyright notices, and even if it turns out not to be strictly required by *GPL it would be no bad thing to preserve them for *GPL content also.

Comment: Regarding BSD: This for sure is true for source code, but what if I only ship the resulting dll?

LGPL: Yes, thats clear

MIT: Does this mean when distributing source code or dlls?

Comment: @maxwell I've quoted a different bit of the BSD licence that should make it clear that it applies to shipments of the DLL (ie, binary form).  The MIT licence also means *all* copies, not restricting things to source code.